# Swift loop from upper value to lower value

Tags: swift, swift4

I have a Swift for loop defined like this:

```
 for i in 20...1 {
    array.append(i)
 }
```

But I get a crash with message

```
  Thread 1: Fatal error: Can't form Range with upperBound < lowerBound
```

What is the fix?

Comment: Easier could be `array += Array((1...20).reversed())`

Comment: @Carpsen90 You should write this up as an answer because it is the best one in terms of getting what the questioner wants in terms of the array, although it technically doesn't answer the question as posed.

Comment: @JeremyP The question is closed now

Comment: @Carpsen90 Never mind then. Your answer is still the best one for this use-case.

Answer (score 12):

You need to reverse the range:

```
for i in (1...20).reversed() {
    array.append(i)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot loop in reverse order like that, if you want you can try this :

```
for i in stride(from: 20, through: 1, by: -1) {
    array.append(i)
}
```

Comment: Why do people upvote without checking?! This doesn't include `1` and doesn't add elements to `array`

Comment: @Carpsen90 I've fixed it.

Comment: @Carpsen90 thank you, I just wanna show him how to loop in reverse order